# Mongoose - Child Schema References Parent Subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to have a Mongoose Schema that resembles the following:

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
    name : String
});

var childSchema = new Schema({
   name : String,
   category : {
      type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref : 'parent.categories'
   }
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    categories : [categorySchema],
    children : [childSchema]
});
```

Basically a child can only have a category that is contained by its parent. Is what I am trying to do possible? If not what is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is only one field `name` in `categorySchema`, maybe you could just put it into `parentSchema` without `population` as below,

```
var childSchema = new Schema({
   name : String,
   category : {
      name: String
   }
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    categories : [{name: String}],
    children : [childSchema]
});
```

When try to insert new `child` into `parent`, you could query the `parent` firstly, then iterate `categories` to get existing one and add it to `children`, save the `parent` as last, sample codes as below

```
Parent.find({_id: parent._id})
      .exec(function(err, p) {
          if (err) throw err;
          var p = new Child({name: 'tt'});
          p.categories.forEach(function(c) {
              if (c /*find the match one*/) {
                  p.category = c; // assign the existing category to children
              }
          });
          // save this parent
          p.save(function(err) {...});
      });
```

---

If there are many fields in `categorySchema`, maybe define it as individual schema could be one option, in case of there are many categories in `Parent` to make parent collection too large.

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    // other fields....
});
var Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);

var childSchema = new Schema({
   name : String,
   category : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Category'}
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    categories : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Category'}],
    children : [childSchema]
});
```

The same logic when try to add new `children` to `parent` document as above.

Comment: I was hoping mongoose had some magical way to do this implicitly, but this is simple enough, thank you.